# Calling a function with parameter on click of a jqgrid cell

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to make a cell colored and clickable if it satisfies certain condition. 
The problem that I am getting is in passing the parameter to the onclick of the element. 
I am doing something like:

```
{
    name: 'numberOfUnits',
    index: 'numberOfUnits',
    sorttype: 'integer',
    cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
        if (...) {
            return 'style="background-color:red" onClick="javascript:showReceivedLockedPieChartDialog(' + '\'' + lockedCellId + '\'' + ')"';
        }
        else {
            return 'style="color:black"';
        }
    }
}
```

I see that the text is being formed as:

```
style="background-color:red" onClick="javascript:showReceivedLockedPieChartDialog('ABC')"
```

I see that it is creating something like this...

```
<td aria-describedby="reportGrid_numberOfUnits" title="13" ABC")"="" onclick="javascript:showReceivedLockedPieChartDialog(" style="background-color:red" role="gridcell">13</td>
```

Please help me pass the parameter to this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ohh yes! Your code shows that the parting of string returned from `cellattr` will be parsed not carefully enough. I find that one should better rewrite the function [formatCol](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.3/js/grid.base.js#L963-993) which will be used internally. I wanted to post next time to trirand suggestion to change the code using `RegEx` matching.

Nevertheless there are some simple rules which could allow to use `cellattr` in the current implementation:

- you should use `style` attribute as the **last attribute** in the string returned from `cellattr`
- you should include additional `' '` blank as the first character of returned value if you returns not only the value for the `style` attribute.
- you should not use words `style`, `title` and `class` only as the names of the corresponding attributes.

The last rule means that you should not use `class="mytitle"` or `title="my class style"`. The parsing of the returned string is not so careful. So such names will have some side effects. As I wrote before the corresponding part of the code jqGrid which parse the results should be changed in my opinion. I will try to post the corresponding suggestions to trirand in the next time.

In your case you should rewrite the code of `cellattr` to

```
cellattr: function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
    if (...) {
        return ' onclick="showReceivedLockedPieChartDialog(' + '\'' +
            lockedCellId + '\'' + ')" style="background-color:red"';
    } else {
        return 'style="color:black"';
    }
}
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/cellattrUsage.htm) shows that the changes works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works perfectly as I wanted. I will take care of these pointers that you gave.

Comment: Actually this is fine but when a string that contain word something like "styletest.com" passed in the function attributes then the on click function breaks the row because of string containg style word.. Any Help?