# jqgrid getCell strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've a jqgrid and a getCell method which returns the value of a cell depending of id. It works only for the first row of the grid, in others identifyImg = false:

```
var ids = jQuery("#myGrid").getDataIDs(); 
        for(var i=0;i<ids.length;i++){
            var identifyImg = $('#myGrid').jqGrid('getCell', i, 'idState');
alert(identifyImg); // return false after first row
            if(identifyImg == '1'){
                 //DO SOMETHING 
              }
            }
```

the column is defined as the follow:

```
{name:'idState',index:'idState', width:55}
```

And is correctly populated with numbers. How can I solve this?

Comment: You should post more full code of jqGrid and the test data which can be used to reproduce the problem. Moreover I don't full understand why such code could be needed. In the most cases one should use `cellattr`, `rowattr` or custom formatter instead of the enumeration which use `getDataIDs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use

```
 $('#myGrid').jqGrid('getCell', ids[i], 'idState');
```

instead of

```
 $('#myGrid').jqGrid('getCell', i, 'idState');
```

I want additionally to mention that in the most cases one don't need use loop over ids returned from `getDataIDs`. It was a good approach in customizing of jqGrid inside of `loadComplete` or `gridComplete` in *old versions of jqGrid*. Now there are more better (from the performance point of view) alternatives. For example if you need to change some style or other attribute of one cell based on the content of one column you can use `cellattr` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6048865/315935), [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408355/315935), [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6509041/315935), [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10956343/315935) or other). If you need to change some attributes of the whole row based on the content of one column you can use `rowattr` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10531680/315935)). In other cases if you need to change content of the cell (not an attribute) based on the content of another cell you can use [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter).